# How can I convert an AT&T iPhone 3GS to a Verizon iPhone 3GS?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I have someone who is not using their AT&T iPhone 3GS. They are willing to give it to me since they have a later model. How can I convert an AT&T iPhone 3GS to a Verizon iPhone 3GS?

What hardware changes need to be made?

Comment: I am amazed this is not possible, the Iphone 3 I want to say I heard has 3.5 million times the computation capacity of the first moon landing mission computer. Don't laugh, and I am sure this is obvious, but I don't know much about electronics. I however am eager to learn more. I have recently aquired an Iphone 3GS for 20 bucks. I was hoping to switch it from at&t to verizon, and then to straight talk as at&t service really sucks around where I live. Really, so there isn't a hardware swap that can be done to make it verizon instead of at&t?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't convert a GSM iPhone to run on the CDMA network, unfortunately. Neither the functional nor the cosmetic components are interchangeable.

If your friend is willing to give you his iPhone and if it's still in decent condition you could probably sell it for enough to fund the purchase of a Verizon iPhone. If it's not in great condition and you still have the urge to tinker, you may be able to find cheap cosmetic parts to restore it to salable condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

AT&T uses GSM, while Verizon uses CDMA. The iPhone 3GS only uses GSM, and thus cannot be used for Verizon.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy the a CDMA board and still use the screen, microphone, and case. I've done it.

Comment: Can you provide links to where you bought your CDMA board and instructions on how to replace it?

Answer (score -1):

It sadly just can't be converted. Back then once you bought it with at&t there was no way to change it to verizon. Also i don't even think it can support at&t.